# Класс не найден

Tags: php, битрикс, orm

Создаю сущность ORM, делаю все как описано [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/dev_bx/create-your-entity-in-b24.php) и спотыкаюсь на первых шагах.
Создаю класс по пути /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/reaction/libs/reaction.php :

```
<?
namespace Reaction;

class ReactionTable extends Main\Entity\DataManager
{
    public static function getTableName()
    {
        return 'reaction';
    }


    public static function getMap()
    {
        return array(
            new Enity\IntigerField('ID', array(
                'primary' => true,
                'autocomplite' => true
            )),
            new Enity\IntigerField('TASK_ID', array(
                'required' => true
            )),
            new Enity\IntigerField('MENTION_USER_ID', array(
                'required' => true
            )),
            new Enity\StringField('TYPE', array(
                'required' => true
            )),
            new Enity\IntigerField('COMMENT_ID')
        );
    }
}
```

И в установщик модуля по пути /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/reaction/install/index.php в InstallDB  добавил:

```
    $db = Application::getConnection();

    $reaction = ReactionTable::getEntity();
    if (! $db->isTableExists($reaction->getDBTableName()))
    {
      $reaction->createDbTable();
    }
```

После чего при установке получаю Class 'ReactionTable' not found (0), с чем может быть связано?

Comment: Неймспейсы проверили?

Comment: В гайде не было об этом ничего сказано, сейчас у меня в index.php подключены только
use Bitrix\Main\Localization\Loc;
use Bitrix\Main\ModuleManager;
use Bitrix\Main\Config\Option;
use Bitrix\Main\EventManager;
use Bitrix\Main\Application;
use Bitrix\Main\IO\Directory;
Я так понимаю чего-то не хватает?

Comment: @u_mulder уже пытался добавлять, безрезультатно use Reaction\ReactionTable;

Comment: тут проблема в автозагрузке. Почитай про PSR-0 PSR-4 и если Битрикс до сих пор не умеет в них, беги оттуда не оглядываясь!

Answer (score 1):

Перед созданием таблицы подключите свой модуль.

```
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('reaction').
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше посоветовали включить `\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('reaction')`, но в моем случае подобное не помогло, т.к модуль вообще перестал устанавливаться.

Если у вас так же, то попробуйте получить код создания sql-таблицы следующим образом:

```
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule("reaction");

use  reaction;

$reactionEntity =  ReactionTable::getEntity();
var_dump($reactionEntity->compileDbTableStructureDump());
```

Затем вызвать получившийся код в   queryExecute в функции InstallDB:

```
$db = Application::getConnection();
$db->queryExecute('xxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

install/index.php 
Нужно в методе DoInstall() поставить перед $this->InstallDB(); 
ModuleManager::registerModule($this->MODULE_ID);

```
function DoInstall() {
    
    $this->InstallEvents();
    $this->InstallOptions();
    $this->InstallFiles();
    $this->InstallPublic();

    ModuleManager::registerModule($this->MODULE_ID);

    $this->InstallDB();

    $APPLICATION->IncludeAdminFile(GetMessage("INSTALL_TITLE"), $this->GetPath()."/install/step.php");

}
```

тогда будет работать создание таблицы через orm

```
function InstallDB() {
    Loader::includeModule($this->MODULE_ID);

    if (!Application::getConnection()->isTableExists(
         Base::getInstance('классTable')->getDBTableName()
            )
       ) {
             Base::getInstance('классTable')->createDbTable();
         }

}
```